# Equations of motion involving terms with four vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, variational-calculus, yang-mills

So I am trying to find equations of motion for the Lagrangian associated with a non-Abelian Gauge theory for $SU(N)$, and while I was doing the math, I was a bit confused the indices.

So I have $\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F^i_{\mu\nu}F^{i\mu\nu}$

Where $F^i_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A^i_\nu -\partial_\nu A^i_\mu +gf^{ijk}A^j_\mu A^k_\nu$

Ok, to find equation of motion, I did:

$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial A^a_\mu} - \partial_\nu(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\nu A_\mu^a)}) = 0 $

For my final answer, I got:

$gf^{abc}A_\nu^cF^{b\mu\nu} - \partial_\nu(F^{a\mu\nu}) = 0$

Then, I realized that [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory) on Yang-Mills Theory has also written the equation of motion for the lagrangian, but they have:

$gf^{abc} A^{\mu b} F^c_{\mu\nu} + \partial^\mu F^a_{\mu\nu} = 0$

I am not good with manipulating the four vector indices. Could someone help me understand if my equation of motion is same as wikipedia's?

Also it is important to say that I do understand that while calculating the equation of motions, I decided to calculate the partial derivative w.r.t to $\nu$ instead of $\mu$ as they did in wikipedia. But the position of the four vector indices in the two answers is what is confusing me.

Comment: Your answer has inconsistent gauge indices. Your first term has free index $b$ (since $a$ and $c$ are contracted) but your second term has free index $a$. Checking that indices are consistent in tensor expressions is as important as checking that dimensions are consistent in, say, Newtonian mechanics. If they are inconsistent, you *know* you’ve made a mistake.

Comment: @G.Smith, ah sorry. It was a typo. I just corrected it.

Comment: There are multiple technical issues raised by this question. If you don’t understand raising and lowering Lorentz indices, you should ask more narrowly about that.

Comment: You have another index inconsistency in the equation under “to find equation of motion”. The second term has three $\nu$‘s and no $\mu$.